# how to change cache behavior settings on existing cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I for the life of me can't find where in the AWS control panel the settings are for changing cache settings on an existing cloudfront distribution. Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AWS console, open Cloudfront service

- Click the Distribution ID you want to modify
- Click **Behaviors** tab
- Check box for the Path Pattern you want to edit
- Click **Edit**

From there you can change default Cache behavior